# QT, How to focus on virtualkeyboard, and use keyboard to control virtualkeyboard

Tags: qt, qtvirtualkeyboard

I'm using virtualkeyboard of Qt5 on embedded device, and no mouse, the keyboard is not full pc keyboard, but just has eleven keys, which include up/down/left/right, enter, esc....

so I want focus on virtualkeyboard, and use up/down/left/right/enter to control virtualkeyboard, simulate mouse to click on virtual key.

how to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtvirtualkeyboard-build.html mentioned that `qtvirtualkeyboard` should be build with `arrow-key-navigation` option. Like this

```
qmake /path/to/qtvirtualkeyboard.pro CONFIG+=arrow-key-navigation
```

Also recommend to build `examples/virtualkeyboard/basic/` with `disable-desktop` option and use it sources as example.