# How to use arrows to navigate through a QtVirtualKeyboard

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtquick2, qtvirtualkeyboard

I want to control the QtVirtualKeyboard with keypresses on a system keyboard, which is an embedded system with limited keys, for example only arrows. The problem is everything I have tried and I have seen suggested doesn't seem to work.

I have seen this post: [QT, How to focus on virtualkeyboard, and use keyboard to control virtualkeyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43244762/qt-how-to-focus-on-virtualkeyboard-and-use-keyboard-to-control-virtualkeyboard)

My .pro has the following config:

```
CONFIG += c++11 arrow-key-navigation disable-desktop qml_debug
```

My main.cpp has:

```
qputenv("QT_IM_MODULE", QByteArray("qtvirtualkeyboard"));
```

I still can´t get the arrow navigation working on the keyboard. My main goal is override some keyboard presses (on the embedded system) and translate them to keyboards movements and presses.

I also tried on the qtcreator example as the post above suggests:

> Also recommend to build examples/virtualkeyboard/basic/ with
> disable-desktop option and use it sources as example.

My environment is Qt Creator 4.7.0 Community, Windows 10, Qt 5.11.1 and

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.VirtualKeyboard 2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

The config is for building qtvirtualkeyboard from the qt source. What you need to do following the guideline of Building Virtual Keyboard as the following link below:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtvirtualkeyboard-build.html

with adding CONFIG+=arrow-key-navigation argument to the build command or adding it directly into .pro file.

After the build is done, run "make install" command under build output destination to deploy your qtvirtualkeyboard then it is ready to use.