# Control qml virtual keyboard using qml code

Tags: qt, qml

I'd like to install a virtual keyboard on my QtQuickApplication using an Input Panel :

```
import QtQuick.VirtualKeyboard 2.1
    InputPanel {
        id: inputPanel
        anchors.fill: parent
        focus: true
    }
```

I have no mouse (nor touchscreen) on my system. I only have a small keyboard (max 10 buttons) to control my GUI.

I'd like to select and type keys from a virtual keyboard using the qml code.

Is there any way to control the virtual keyboard using some qml code ?

Comment: how do you want to control the virtual keyboard if you nave no real keyboard no mouse?

Comment: Since I am working on an embedded system, my inputs are limited to few buttons. I'd like to use these buttons (or combination of buttons) to navigate into my InputPanel and to select keys I'd like to write.

Comment: You can try to bind your keys to a real keys in C++. `QKeyEvent *event = new QKeyEvent ( QEvent::KeyPress, Qt::Key_Enter, Qt::NoModifier);
QCoreApplication::postEvent (engine->rootObjects().first(), event);`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I can't code every key with my few buttons. I'd like to use them to control the virtual keyboard. Do you mean it's possible to navigate into the virtual keyboard using real Key Events ?

Comment: I rewrote the question to be clearer

Comment: Not every key. I mean you can use your keys to emulate maybe arrows and enter press so you will be able to navigate through the virtual keyboard.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217015/discussion-between-tthibalti-and-folibis).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution thanks to folibis.

Qt virtual keyboard can be controlled using arrow keys but it has to be compiled again using `CONFIG+=arrow-key-navigation` as described in this topic : 
[How to use arrows to navigate through a QtVirtualKeyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54719106/how-to-use-arrows-to-navigate-through-a-qtvirtualkeyboard)

and in this Qt documentation : 
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54719106/how-to-use-arrows-to-navigate-through-a-qtvirtualkeyboard](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtvirtualkeyboard-build.html)

Then, as folibis said in his previous comment, arrow key events can be simulated using QKeyEvent objects :
`QKeyEvent *event = new QKeyEvent ( QEvent::KeyPress, Qt::Key_Enter, Qt::NoModifier); QCoreApplication::postEvent (engine->rootObjects().first(), event);`